# How move to a another page in paginatortemplate that contains selected row

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, datatable

I have a primefaces datatable with a paginator template in selection mode. If I am at first page, by exemple, and I select in my bean a record that is in page 4 of paginatortemplate datatable, how can I move programmatically to the page 4 to view the selected row?

xhtml:

```
<p:dataTable id="tablaVista" 
   var="u"
   value="#{mtoArticulosBean.listaGeneral}"
   emptyMessage="#{msgs.NoHayRegistros}"
   paginator="true" rows="12"  
   paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink}   PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} "  
   selection="#{mtoArticulosBean.registroSel}"
   selectionMode="single" 
   rowKey="#{u.codArticulo}">
   .....
</p:datatable
```

mtoArticulosBean:

```
....

setRegistroSel(getListaGeneral().get(42));

....
```

The user still sees the page 1 although the selected record is on page 4

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can (should) use the 'first' attribute of the datatable. When setting the selection, calculate on which page it is (record number / page size) and makecthat available in a bean.

In your xhtml you can then do

```
<p:datatable first="#{myBean.first}"....
```

(See also [Primefaces: set page on datatable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10006778/primefaces-set-page-on-datatable))