# How to jump in Primefaces dataTable to last page from the bean?

Tags: jquery, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, datatable

I have into my .xhtml a datatable looking like this :

```
<p:dataTable var="category" value="#{beanView.categories}" paginator="true" rows="5" 
 paginatorTemplate="{RowsPerPageDropdown} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {CurrentPageReport} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}"
 rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10" id="categoryDT" styleClass="categoryClass"    
 editable="true" lazy="false" rowKey="#{category.id}">
 <!-- columns -->
<f:facet name="footer">
    <p:commandButton id="btnNewCat" 
      oncomplete="jQuery('.categoryClass').find('span.ui-icon-pencil').last().click();" 
    actionListener="#{beanView.onNewCategory}" 
    update="categoryDT" icon="ui-icon-plus" title="New Category" value="New Category" ></p:commandButton>
</f:facet></p:dataTable>
```

And my bean **beanView** :

```
public void onNewCategory(final ActionEvent actionEvent) {

    try {
        int rowCount = dataTable.getRowCount();
        int rowsPerPage = dataTable.getRows();
        int lastPage = rowCount / rowsPerPage;
        int rowFirst = (lastPage * rowsPerPage);

        if (rowCount >= rowsPerPage) {
            dataTable.setFirst(rowFirst);
            dataTable.setPageLinks(lastPage + 1);
            dataTable.setRowIndex(rowCount - 1);
        } else {
            ....
        }

        ....
     }
 }
```

But this actually doesnt work! the last page will not be show!

It's possible to Click on the last Page button of my datatable from the bean? or is there another way to solve it!

Thanks for helping

Comment: Try to replace the oncomplete with this: `PF('dataTableWV').paginator.setPage(PF('dataTableWV').paginator.cfg.pageCount - 1);`

Comment: Oh! nice! this one works! but how to get the : PF('widgetcategoryDT').paginator.setPage into the Bean??

Comment: Using this: `RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("PF('widgetcategoryDT').paginator.setPage ....')");`

Comment: Oh yes!! work! can you please post it as an answer? so i can choose it!!?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can achieve this by the `oncomplete` of the commandButton:

```
<p:commandButton oncomplete="PF('dataTableWV').paginator.setPage(PF('dataTableWV').paginator.cfg.pageCount - 1);"/>
```

Or from the managed bean:

```
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("PF('dataTableWV').paginator.setPage(PF('dataTableWV').paginator.cfg.pageCount - 1);");
```

Note: `dataTableWV` is the widgetVar of the dataTable.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just adding to Hatem's answer.

If you need a check to only do that when adding/creating a row to a datatable after success and no validation error occurred, you can use:

```
action="#{myBean.createSelection}"
oncomplete="if ( !args.validationFailed &amp;&amp; args.created ) { PF('myDataTable').paginator.setPage(PF('myDataTable').paginator.cfg.pageCount - 1); }" />
```

The oncomplete method has the arguments `xhr`, `status` and `args` that can be used by controllers to return what actually happened.

In the above case, we are adding some entity to a datatable and we only want to page to the last one if validation didn't fail and a new entity was created, but not on update or delete.

In your controller, you can/should do:

```
    public void createSelection()
    {
        T selectedEntity = getSelectedEntity();
        
        T persistedEntity = null;
        
        try
        {
            persistedEntity = getEntityService().create( selectedEntity );
        }
        catch ( CreateException e )
        {
            ...

            return;
        }
        
        ...            
        
        PrimeFaces.current().ajax().addCallbackParam( "created", Boolean.TRUE );            
    }
```