# How can I get the list of values in the drop down of <p:autocomplete> after reset button is pressed.

Tags: jquery, jsf, primefaces

I have one primefaces autocomplete with dropdown and one reset button.

After selecting one value from the dropdown list if I am press the reset button, autocomplete dropdown becomes blank(i.e it is getting reseted). But the problem is after resetting the autocomplete I am not able to get the values in the autocomplete drop down list.

Here  goes my code

index.xhtml

```
<p:autocomplete id="name" binding="#{myBean.name}" value="#{myBean.personName}" completeMethod="#{myBean.retrieveNames}" dropdown="true"/>

<p:commandButton value="Reset" action="#{myBean.reset}"  immediate="true" update="@form">
```

MyBean.java

```
private String personName;
private UIInput name;


public void resetUIValue(UIInput uiObj) {  
    uiObj.setSubmittedValue(null);
    uiObj.setLocalValueSet(false);
    uiObj.setValid(true);
    uiObj.setValue("");
}
public void reset() {
        this.clearFormValues();
        this.resetUIValue(this.name);

}
public void clearFormValues()
{
   this.name="";
}
public List<String> retrieveNames(String query)
{
    List<String> result=new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        result.add(query+i);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: look maybe this answer will help more http://stackoverflow.com/a/8391552/1692632

Comment: @Darka Thanks for your response. But it didnt provide me solution to my problem. I have also tried by not resetting my autocomplete. But after reset when I update the panel which include this autocomplete, I do not receive autocomplete dropdown. Here with reset functionality my concern is more for retrieving my dropdown list in autocomplete which is some how lost after updation of the panel.

Answer (score 1):

I pasted your code and got 3 errors:

1) this.name=""; is not String i changed to personName

2)p:commandButton should end with />

3)at least, when I tried access page, I got error, that it can't find p:autocomplete, so I changed it to p:autocomplete p:autoComplete

After that when I press reset autoComplete still works.

Here is full code:

```
 <h:form id="test" prependId="false">

 <p:autoComplete id="name" binding="#{beanT.name}" value="#{beanT.personName}" completeMethod="#{beanT.retrieveNames}" dropdown="true"/>
 <p:commandButton value="Reset" action="#{beanT.reset}"  immediate="true" update="@form" />

 </h:form>


 @ManagedBean(name="beanT")
 @ViewScoped
 public class TestBean {
    private String personName;
    private UIInput name;


    public UIInput getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(UIInput name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public void resetUIValue(UIInput uiObj) {  
        uiObj.setSubmittedValue(null);
        uiObj.setLocalValueSet(false);
        uiObj.setValid(true);
        uiObj.setValue("");
    }
    public void reset() {
            this.clearFormValues();
            this.resetUIValue(this.name);

    }
    public void clearFormValues()
    {
       this.setPersonName("");
    }
    public List<String> retrieveNames(String query)
    {
        List<String> result=new ArrayList<String>();
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        {
            result.add(query+i);
        }
        return result;
    }
    public String getPersonName() {
        return personName;
    }
    public void setPersonName(String personName) {
        this.personName = personName;
    } 
 }
```

Comment: hi that all was typing mistakes these are present only in this que.  Not in actual code. Sorry for those mistakes. But actual code is still not working