# PrimeFaces SelectOneMenu: Empty String is submitted as null

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

**web.xml**

```
[...]
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.INTERPRET_EMPTY_STRING_SUBMITTED_VALUES_AS_NULL</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>
[...]
```

**view.xhtml**

```
[...]
<p:selectOneMenu id="input1" value="#{myBean.value1}">
    <f:selectItem itemValue="" itemLabel="..." />
</p:selectOneMenu>

<p:inputText id="input2" value="#{myBean.value2}" />
[...]
```

**MyBean.java**

```
[...]
private String value1;
private String value2;
[...]
```

I leave `input2` blank, submit the form and inspect the values in the managed bean:

- `value2` is an empty String - as expected!
- `value1` is null

Why is `value1` null and not an empty String? If I want the value to be an empty String, how can I achieve this?

**Update**
The "problem" is in the class `com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.MenuRenderer`:

```
public Object getConvertedValue(...) {
    [...]
    if (RIConstants.NO_VALUE.equals(newValue)) {
        return null;
    }
    [...]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check this  [JSF 2 - Bean Validation: validation failed -> empty values are replaced with last valid values from managed bean.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3933786/jsf-2-bean-validation-validation-failed-empty-values-are-replaced-with-las)

if you want to set the `value1` as empty string then you can use this code.

```
public Object getSubmittedValue() {
if (submittedValue == null && !isValid() && considerEmptyStringNull(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance())) {
    return "";
}
else {
    return submittedValue;
}
```

}

Comment: I don't think that this is my problem. I don't use any validators.