# Old valid value is restored after a validation error

Tags: validation, jsf-2, richfaces

I have an undesirable behavior in my application, and I don't know how I can remove it.

I have a required field and a "Save" button in a form. Here are the steps to reproduce my behavior :

1. The first test is to fill the field and click on the button => OK
2. Reset the field to an empty value and click again on the button => the old valid value is restore and the error message is displayed.

The issue : the message tells a value is required, but the field is no more empty !

Is there a way to avoid this restore of the last valid value ?

Comment: take a look at this https://www.google.com/search?q=jsf+old+value+shown+after+validation+failed&oq=jsf+old+value+shown+after+validation+failed&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l2j69i60j0.7797j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: Ensure that the associated managed-bean in not `@SessionScoped`.

Comment: This is most likely related to http://stackoverflow.com/a/8393808. Workaround: use ajax to submit the form and don't update the inputs.